# Why does the flatpickr in the ajax does not auto create the pick date function ? (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, date, flatpickr

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="projectDeadlineFlatpickrNewProjectLabel" class="input-label">Select Date</label>

            <div id="projectDeadlineNewProjectFlatpickr" class="js-flatpickr flatpickr-custom input-group"
                data-hs-flatpickr-options='{
                "appendTo": "#projectDeadlineNewProjectFlatpickr",
                "dateFormat": "Y-m-d",
                "wrap": true
                }'>
            <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-text" data-bs-toggle>
                <i class="bi-calendar-week"></i>
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="filterSelectDate" id="filterSelectDate" class="flatpickr-custom-form-control form-control" placeholder="Select Start Date" data-input value="<?=$datefilter?>">
            </div>
        </div>
```

the above code works normally but

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './includes/components/stock-cart/reconciliation-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    client: data.cart_id,
                },
                success: function(response) {

                    const returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                    const masterId = returnedData.masterId;
                    const cartData = returnedData.cartData;

                    console.log(cartData.length);

                    const modalBody = $('#modalBody');
                    
                    for(let i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {

                        const max = 0;

                        if(cartData[i].cart_amount_current > 0){
                            const max = cartData[i].cart_amount_current;
                        }

                        // MAIN DIV WITH CLASS="BORDER-LINE"
                        const div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.classList.add("border-line");

                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationArraySize", cartData.length));
                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationCartId" + i, cartData[i].cart_id));
                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationMasterId" + i, masterId));
                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationAmount" + i, cartData[i].cart_amount_default));
                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationCost" + i, cartData[i].cart_rate));
                        div.appendChild(createHiddenInput("reconciliationRemarks" + i, cartData[i].cart_remarks));

                        // 1ST SUB DIV 
                        const row1 = document.createElement("div");
                        row1.classList.add("row", "mb-4");
                        row1.innerHTML = `
                            <label for="cartIdLabel" style="font-size: 15px;" 
                            class="col-sm-12 col-form-label form-label">${cartData[i].cart_batch}</label>
                        `;

                        const row2 = document.createElement("div");
                        row2.classList.add("row");
                        row2.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="projectDeadlineFlatpickrNewProjectLabel" class="input-label">Select Date</label>

                            <div id="projectDeadlineNewProjectFlatpickr" class="js-flatpickr flatpickr-custom input-group"
                                data-hs-flatpickr-options='{
                                "appendTo": "#projectDeadlineNewProjectFlatpickr",
                                "dateFormat": "Y-m-d",
                                "wrap": true
                                }'>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-text" data-bs-toggle>
                                <i class="bi-calendar-week"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" name="filterSelectDate" id="filterSelectDate" class="flatpickr-custom-form-control form-control" placeholder="Select Start Date" data-input value="<?=$datefilter?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        `;
                        
                        const formattedAmount = parseFloat(cartData[i].cart_amount_current).toFixed(2);
                        const row3 = document.createElement("div");
                        row3.classList.add("row", "mb-4");
                        row3.innerHTML = `
                            <label for="amountLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-label">Amount (RMB)</label>
                            <label style="margin-top: 11px;" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label form-label">${formattedAmount}</label>
                            <label for="amountLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-label">Cost (RMB)</label>
                            <label style="margin-top: 11px;" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label form-label">${cartData[i].cart_rate}</label>
                        `;

                        const row4 = document.createElement("div");
                        row4.classList.add("row", "mb-4");
                        row4.innerHTML = `
                            <label for="amountLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-label">Amount (USD)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input style="margin-top: 11px;" class="js-result form-control px-2 amount" type="number"
                                min="0.000001" max="${max}" step="any" id="amountLabel" name="amount${i}" placeholder="Amount"
                                onchange="calculateTotal();" onclick="this.select()" onfocus="this.select()" oninput="calculateReconciliationTotal()" required>
                            </div>
                            <label for="amountLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-label">Rate (USD)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input style="margin-top: 11px;" class="js-result form-control px-2 amount" type="number"
                                min="0.000001" max="${max}" step="any" id="amountLabel" name="amount${i}" placeholder="Rate Amount"
                                onchange="calculateTotal();" onclick="this.select()" onfocus="this.select()" oninput="calculateReconciliationTotal()" required>
                            </div>
                        `;

                        const row5 = document.createElement("div");
                        row5.classList.add("row", "mb-4");
                        row5.innerHTML = `
                            <label for="amountLabel" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label form-label">Amount Deduct (USD)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="js-result form-control px-2 amount" type="number"
                                min="0.000001" max="${max}" step="any" id="amountLabel" name="amount${i}" placeholder="Amount Deduct"
                                onchange="calculateTotal();" onclick="this.select()" onfocus="this.select()" oninput="calculateReconciliationTotal()" required>
                            </div>
                        `;
                        }
                        div.appendChild(row1);
                        div.appendChild(row2);
                        div.appendChild(row3);
                        div.appendChild(row4);
                        div.appendChild(row5);                  
                        modalBody.append(div);
                    }
                }
            });
```

when i place into the javascript .ajax, it does not work and does nothing

It is the same code with the above, and the above works fine, Im sorta stuck at the ajax part, i have modify the id to something else, but still nothing happen, it only display the date value instead of allowing others to click it and pick a date

Comment: there is not even a hint of `AJAX` in that code

Comment: my bad, i have updated it

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is here. Please edit the question and add a proper explanation of what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, which code is responsible for it, when it should happen and then what actually happens (check error logs, browser console etc for potential error messages) and include what debugging you've done to narrow the issue down. Is it really a JS _and_ PHP issue?